# WandB - Why are "step" ticks in diagrams calculated differently from given? (Python)

Tags: python, module, diagram

I evaluate a deep learning model (StyleGan2-Ada-Pytorch). The procedure is to calculate the metrics afterwards based on a log file (this takes a long time, therefore not done in training).

The metric was logged only every few iterations, so `epoch` is something like `0, 50, 100, 150` and has each time a corresponding metric.
I iterate through the list and give each item to WandB:  `wandb.log( metric, step=epoch )`

**Problem:** When looking at the overall WandB dashboard, the data points are not on the given step (x-axis tick). They are off by some scaled delta. For example: Instead of starting at the given `0` step, the value is displayed at position `19.6`. This differs for every entry:

| epoch tick (step) | diagram x-position delta |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | `+19.6` (see screenshot) |
| 50 | `+9.8` |
| 100 | `0` |
| 150 | `-9.8` |
| 200 | `-19.6` |

[image: overview dashboard]

**But**, when I click on the specific run to view its details, the values are displayed correctly:
[image: detail dashboard]

I tried to play with the axis scales, smoothing and so on. Did not help.

This is super annoying, has somebody an idea what's wrong?

---

#### Minimal Example:

```
import os
import wandb
os.environ["WANDB_API_KEY"] = 'Your API Key'

step_metric = {
    0  : 2.2,
    50 : 29.3,
    100: 45,
    150: 67.4,
    200: 182
}

run = wandb.init(  project = "stackoverflow", group = 'run1'  )

for key, value in step_metric.items():
    mydict = { "A": value , "B" : value*2 }
    wandb.log( mydict, step=int(key) )

run.finish()
```

Comment: hm, maybe you should ask that in the wandb slack forum

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One of the devs responded to my [issue](https://github.com/wandb/client/issues/2059).
They state to avoid using the `step` parameter and insert it instead as an extra property in the `values` dict.
(I personally think it's currently a bug)

**Updated code:**

```
    mydict = { "A": value , "B" : value*2, epoch=int(key) }
    wandb.log( mydict )
```

Change the x-axis in the diagram afterwards:

[image: wandb]

Comment: The dict should be `mydict = {"A": value , "B" : value*2, "x-axis": key}` according to your link.